# composition of graph of maps

Tags: differential-geometry

In my differential geometry class, the graph defined as below:

Let $F:M\to N$ be a smooth map between manifolds of dimensions $m$ and $n$, then $${\rm graph}(F)=\{(F(p), p)|p\in M\}\subseteq N\times M.$$

And the professor mentioned that graph usually defined as subset of $M\times N$ rather than $N\times M$. An advantage of the convention above is that it gives ${\rm graph} (F'\circ F)={\rm graph}(F')\circ {\rm graph}(F)$ under composition of relations.

$${\rm graph}(F'\circ F)=\{(F'\circ F(p),p)|p \in M\},$$
but I don't understand how to composition the two graphs of the right side of the above equation. On Wikipedia, composition of relations is defined as: If $R\in X\times Y$ and $S\in Y\times Z$ are two binary relations, their composition $$R;S=\{(x, z)\in X\times Z:\text{there exists }y\in Y\text{ such that }(x, y)\in R\text{ and }(y, x)\in S\}.$$

But here ${\rm graph}(F')=\{(F'(p),p)\}$ and ${\rm graph}(F)=\{(F(p),p)\}$, they don't have a common "$Y$" part, then how to composite?

Comment: You haven't said what the domain and codomain of $F'$ are.  That is likely where your common $Y$ is.

Comment: The order of the factors does not affect the graph of the composition.

Comment: @Randall  My professor didn't say what those are. At first I thought that was also $M \to N$, but after read you comment, I think it may be N to some other manifold.

Comment: Correct, otherwise "composition" makes no sense.

Comment: @Randall I think it definitely be N to some manifold, since if not, the composition of map on the left side would not be defined, thanks!